# Unix Permissions Checks

Tags: java, python, unix, sudo

Assume that my server 's' is running as 'a' user and it is receiving queries from 'b' user. Is there a way my server 's' can check if 'b' user has permissions to run script web_scrape.py as user 'c'?

where,

1. 's' is a Java server,
2. 'b' is a human unix user,
3. 'a' and 'c' are software unix users.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "'b' user has sudo permissions over 'c' user".  But I suspect that it is moot.

Comment: @StephenC I've rephrased the sentence ..

Comment: I see.  In fact, mapping from a human person ('b') to a UNIX account ('c') is a different problem.  You should solve it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Not unless user `a` is `root`, or has sudo ALL privilege.

If `a` is `root` or has sudo ALL privilege, then it could use `sudo -U <user> --list <command>` to find out if `<user>` is permitted to run `sudo <command>`.

Note that it doesn't actually matter what language the server or script are written in.  The server needs to be able to tell the OS to run a `sudo` command, but most languages are capable of doing that.  (In Java you would use `Process`, `ProcessBuilder`, etc in the normal way.)

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! This makes sense.

Comment: sudo -n -l -u softuser -U humanuser web_scrape.py. This works for me! Am I missing anything?

Comment: According to my reading of `man sudo`, the `-u` option has no effect with `-l`.  It will be ignored.  As I said previously, mapping from "human user" to "linux user" is not something that `sudo` does.  You need to solve that problem separately.

Answer (score 0):

`$ id -u b`

if value equals 0 then b is root user